# access and create new array from the array cell of struct

Tags: matlab, struct, cell-array

In file .mat in matlab,there is an array cell 'channels' 1x1 struct. I want to create a new array which only contains ['LAG_01' 'LAG_02' ... 'LPG_12'].

Is there any method to do that ?

Thanks,

channels

ans =

```
X.LAG_01.: 'LAG_01'
X.LAG_02.: 'LAG_02'
X.LAG_03.: 'LAG_03'
X.LAG_04.: 'LAG_04'
X.LAG_05.: 'LAG_05'
X.LAG_06.: 'LAG_06'
X.LAG_07.: 'LAG_07'
X.LAG_08.: 'LAG_08'
X.LAG_09.: 'LAG_09'
X.LAG_10.: 'LAG_10'
X.LAG_11.: 'LAG_11'
X.LAG_12.: 'LAG_12'
X.LAG_13.: 'LAG_13'
X.LAG_14.: 'LAG_14'
X.LAG_15.: 'LAG_15'
X.LAG_16.: 'LAG_16'
X.LAG_17.: 'LAG_17'
X.LAG_18.: 'LAG_18'
X.LAG_19.: 'LAG_19'
X.LAG_20.: 'LAG_20'
X.LAG_21.: 'LAG_21'
X.LAG_22.: 'LAG_22'
X.LAG_23.: 'LAG_23'
X.LAG_24.: 'LAG_24'
X.LAG_25.: 'LAG_25'
X.LAG_26.: 'LAG_26'
X.LAG_27.: 'LAG_27'
X.LAG_28.: 'LAG_28'
X.LAG_29.: 'LAG_29'
X.LAG_30.: 'LAG_30'
X.LAG_31.: 'LAG_31'
X.LAG_32.: 'LAG_32'
X.LAG_33.: 'LAG_33'
X.LAG_34.: 'LAG_34'
X.LAG_35.: 'LAG_35'
X.LAG_36.: 'LAG_36'
X.LAG_37.: 'LAG_37'
X.LAG_38.: 'LAG_38'
X.LAG_39.: 'LAG_39'
X.LAG_40.: 'LAG_40'
X.LAG_41.: 'LAG_41'
X.LAG_42.: 'LAG_42'
X.LAG_43.: 'LAG_43'
X.LAG_44.: 'LAG_44'
X.LAG_45.: 'LAG_45'
X.LAG_46.: 'LAG_46'
X.LAG_47.: 'LAG_47'
X.LAG_48.: 'LAG_48'
X.LAG_49.: 'LAG_49'
X.LAG_50.: 'LAG_50'
X.LAG_51.: 'LAG_51'
X.LAG_52.: 'LAG_52'
X.LAG_53.: 'LAG_53'
X.LAG_54.: 'LAG_54'
X.LAG_55.: 'LAG_55'
X.LAG_56.: 'LAG_56'
X.LAG_57.: 'LAG_57'
X.LAG_58.: 'LAG_58'
X.LAG_59.: 'LAG_59'
X.LAG_60.: 'LAG_60'
X.LAG_61.: 'LAG_61'
X.LAG_62.: 'LAG_62'
X.LAG_63.: 'LAG_63'
X.LAG_64.: 'LAG_64'
X.LPG_01.: 'LPG_01'
X.LPG_02.: 'LPG_02'
X.LPG_03.: 'LPG_03'
X.LPG_04.: 'LPG_04'
X.LPG_05.: 'LPG_05'
X.LPG_06.: 'LPG_06'
X.LPG_11.: 'LPG_11'
X.LPG_12.: 'LPG_12'
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct2cell` is your friend:

> ```
> C = struct2cell(S) converts the M-by-N structure S (with P fields) 
> into a P-by-M-by-N cell array C.
> ```